# Is there a way to display a JSON file as an accordion in a web browser?

Tags: json, angular, web, accordion

I need to make a user friendly accordion structure displaying the contents of certain JSON file tags in an accordion menu, but I'm not sure where to start doing this?
Is there a way for me to use Angular to achieve this?
(I'm new to Angular so I don't fully know what it's capable of)

```
{"name" : "addition",
"inputs" : "2 integer numbers", 
"outputs" :"sum of two numbers", 
"link" : "xyz.com", 
"date" : "24-10-2005}
```

I want to display only name, inputs and outputs

Comment: can you show us the JSON file tags?

Comment: If you're not sure about how to achieve this I would suggest staying away from Angular as this may be additional learning that would probably hinder your progress.

Comment: {"name" : "addition", "inputs" : "2 integer numbers", "outputs" :"sum of two numbers", "link" : "xyz.com", "date" : "24-10-2005"}                         i want to display only name, inputs and outputs

Comment: please add that to the question. Any data can, in theory, be turned into anything. Find out how to read properties from the data, if you don't know, and find out how to create an accordion. Then work out how you would use the data to create the parts of the accordion. Break the problem down into small steps and each part individually becomes much easier to understand, research and implement. Plus you also end up with a plan for your work.

Comment: You can achive this with Object.keys() and *ngFor  + recursive that calls the same component